# GPO security filter with powershell Set-GPPermissions cmdlet

Tags: security, powershell, filter, permissions, gpo

When i try to change security settings for "Authenticated users" on MyGPO, it return me a error: 
    Set-GPPermissions : The operation cannot be completed because "Authenticated users" is not a valid security group.

I use this code:

```
Set-GPPermissions -Name MyGPO -PermissionLevel none -TargetName "Authenticated users" -TargetType group
```

Comment: The syntax seems ok, can you be more specific about Windows version of domain controllers and the computer where you run the PowerShell cmdlet?

Comment: I actually found a solution for this issue, a hotfix can be used for solving this issue.
But unfortunately in my case it can  not be used, because hotfix install requires a system restart. I will look for a DOS command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i found the solution, it a known issue with Set-GPPermissions / Get-GPPermissions Cmdlet on Windows 7 / 2008R2. A hotfix (kb978838) is available, it can be downloaded [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978838).
System must be restarted after installation...